# get only numbers between tags

Tags: php, html-parsing

i want get number between tags that not hex or unicode in a html content
like this with regular expression

```
<a href="/sam2/example-3.php">go to page 13</a> 0x91 0x26 exchange hello98.25 &#8230;
```

return

13 and 98.25

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally write my regex for it

```
'/(?:&#\d{2,4};)|(?:0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+)|(\d+[\.\d]*)|<\s*[^>]+>/i'
```

it,s work perfet

Comment: If my answer above has satisfied your needs, please, mark it as "Accepted answer", which is a 'check' icon. Thank you. =)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any use for what you are trying to do... if you wish to create paginations, you should work with GET or POST data, example:

```
 <a href="/sam2/example-3.php?page=13">go to page 13</a>
```

And then you can retrieve the page value and use it in your script

```
 $page = $_GET['page'];
```

**But anyway, answering your question:**

```
$content = '<a href="/sam2/example-3.php">go to page 13</a> 0x91 0x26 exchange hello98.25 &#8230;';

$page_id = preg_replace('/(\"(.*)\"|0x.[0-9]+|\&\#.[0-9]+|[^0-9\.])/', ' ', $content);

echo $page_id;

//Result: 13 98.25 (string with each number separated by space)
```

Good luck.